# Deduce why an arbitrary vector is the sum of kernels of endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I had the following question in one of my exams:

> Let $E$ be a non-zero finite dimensional vector space and let $f \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ be an endomorphism such that $f^3 = f$. Prove that, for any $x \in E$ we have $x - f^2(x) \in \ker(f)$, $f^2(x) - f(x) \in \ker(f+\operatorname{Id}_E)$ and $f^2(x) + f(x) \in \ker(f-\operatorname{Id}_E)$. Deduce that $x \in \ker(f) + \ker(f+Id_E) + \ker(f-Id_E)$.

I was easily able to show that the first three statements were true. However, I can't seem to deduce that $x \in \ker(f) + \ker(f+\operatorname{Id}_E) + \ker(f-\operatorname{Id}_E)$ from the previous statements. Kindly elucidate how we can make the deduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*. Write $x$ as a linear combination of $x-f^2(x)$ and $f^2(x)-f(x)$ and $f^2(x)+f(x)$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now!